# Do any moral philosophers discuss 'validation'?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, truth, altruism, art

Do philosphers of ethics talk about validation?

The idea that my life or projects or person have some intrinsic value, specifically not just those that are innate to persons?

Maybe my tags seem a little random, but seems like altruism / truth / art are the best bets, to me.

Comment: "Valorization" may be a closer term here?

Comment: @JosephWeissman good idea. i hated cleaver, who used that term